# How can I convert a series of images to WebM in FFmpeg?

Tags: windows-7, ffmpeg, webm

I’ve got a series of JPG images going from `108-AN-001` to `108-AN-045`.
I need to convert these into a single [WebM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM) video file.

I've tried this command:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i 108-AN-%03d.jpg -vf 12 output.webm
```

However, it would seem to be broken on Windows 7, as I get this error in the console:

```
[image2 @ 02d7f7c0] Could find no file with path '108-AN-C:\Users\Irastris\Desktop\Programs\FFMPEG\imagestoavi.bat3d.jpg' and index in the range 0-4
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

`%0` is being expanded to the name of your batch file instead of being passed to `ffmpeg` as a template for multiple filenames.

You should use a double percentage mark to prevent this: `108-AN-%%03d.jpg`

Comment: Thank you! Now I just need to play with the framerate. :P